# Why linkedin_scraper scrape same LinkedIn profile on different URL

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, linkedin-api

```
from linkedin_scraper import Person
        for line in f: #line is url
            try:
                person = Person(line, driver=browser, scrape=True, close_on_complete=False)
                print(person.name)
                print(person.company)
                print(person.job_title)
                print(person.educations)
                print(person.experiences)
                print(person.interests)
                print(person.location)
                print(person.linkedin_url)
                print(person.also_viewed_urls)

            except NoSuchElementException as e:
                print("ERROR MESSAGE FOR DEVELOPER: ", e)
```

Output:

> Reham John None tianshi international [None at b'sirsyed college of
> commerece' from None to None, b'maric from govr high school and bcom
> from sir syed college' at b'govt high school, sir syed college
> jaranwala' from 2006 to 2007] [b'tianshi international' at None from
> None to None for None based at None] [] Germany
> https://www.linkedin.com/in/reham-john-498671ba/
>
> [] Amjad John None tianshi international [None at b'sirsyed college of
> commerece' from None to None, b'maric from govr high school and bcom
> from sir syed college' at b'govt high school, sir syed college
> jaranwala' from 2006 to 2007] [b'tianshi international' at None from
> None to None for None based at None, b'CEO' at None from None to None
> for None based at None, b'Chief Executive Officer' at b'John Group of
> companies' from 2000 – to  for 20 yrs based at Islamabad] [] Federal
> Capial &AJK, Pakistan
> https://www.linkedin.com/in/amjad-john-7033bb17a/
>
> []

Two different on different companies but it will show previous person experience

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by providing the following arguments to the `Person` function:

```
Person(
  linkedin_url=None, 
  name=None, 
  about=[], 
  experiences=[], 
  educations=[], 
  interests=[], 
  accomplishments=[], 
  company=None, 
  job_title=None, 
  driver=None, 
  scrape=True
)
```

This will ensure that you get different values for each iteration/`Person`.